# Volume of the region?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Hello I'm trying to solve this equation but kinda stuck.

The problem is as follows;

> The region in the first quadrant bounded above by the line y =2, below by the curve y=2sinx, $0\le x\le\pi/2$, and on the left by the y-axis, about the line y=2

Now I'm bit confused on how to approach the problem because it is bit complicated when I have to get the volume about the y=2 axis since the equation is stated as a function of x.

Could someone please help me out to solve this problem?

Comment: Hint: You could always make simple transformation of the axes (like $y' = y-2$) so that the line $y=2$ becomes the new $y'$ axis (and note that this will not change the volume).

Comment: I did approach it in the similar way actually, but I got stuck when I read the part which says about the line y=2, since if I simplify the function to be a function of x, it'll be bit complicated to integrate as it'll be a sin inverse function.

Comment: You should not get any inverse sin functions. When you make the transformation, the curve $y = 2\sin x$ just becomes $y'+2 = 2\sin x$.

Comment: True, but what I'm confused is that is it possible to approach the problem by finding the volume about the x-axis instead of the y-axis? 

In order to find the volume about the y axis means that I need to have a function of y right?

Comment: I think I made a typo in my very first comment: The standard process rotates about the $x-$axis, which is the line $y=0$, we want to rotate about the line $y=2$ which is the new $x-$axis under the transformed axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top border of the region is $y=2$.  The bottom border is $y = 2 \sin x$.  So the radius of the disk (with thickness $dx$) will be $2 - 2 \sin x$.  From there you add up all of the disks in the region by integrating over $x$ from $0$ to $\pi / 2$.

The volume is then

$$V = \int_0^{\pi/2}\pi(2-2 \sin x)^2 dx.$$

Are you able to take it from there?